# ElectroVehicle batteries: safety issues

Tags: batteries, safety

For a EV battery recycling project I am going to play with EV batteries.
I will read out parameters from them (element configuration, charge, etc).

I will NEVER try to recharge nor dismantle them: other people on another (hopefully safe) site is going to work on recharging them and one battery will be moved to my lab only for reading purposes.

Wandering around the Net I saw that there are two ways to **manage battery safety**:

- **lighthearted**: plastic goggles, no protection against fire and explosion, battery on the lab floor;
- **Fort Knox-like**: steel walls, fire brigade ready in the parking, fire extinguishers, and so on.

I would assume the truth is half way, perhaps a little bit more on the fire brigade side.

Is there any reference or regulation about how a proper test environment should be done? Any example from a real company?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you won't recharge them, what will you do with them when they are discharged? Seems a waste or do you have an inexhaustible supply of batteries?

Comment: @SolarMike, I am not the only one working on the batteries. Somebody else is working on recharge in another site. We are in a wider recycling project.

Comment: Then you should make the situation clear in the original question - don't leave relevant information composting in comments, people don't read comments to build your question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to read out parameters and operate the battery in standard conditions, so no short circuiting and other fun stuff, your normal lab is sufficient. Just do not wear any metal rings or stuff.

If you want to do more intensive testing, short circuiting, overchargning, temperature stability tests, an environment where the battery can burn down safely is more apprechiated.

My ex-employer had concrete bunkers for extensive testing, but normal development / testing was done in the normal office, without any special safety regulations.

Word of advice though:

Batteries burn at night. So whatever you're testing, do not store them over night in your office, but an outside location.

We used standard seafreight containers for storage.

Comment: Thank you. I like the "Batteries burn at night" thing :-)

Comment: Yeah, that should be made a slogan for Electrical Engineering website :D

Comment: Letting the magic smoke out of anything is usually the problem...